# Virtual ethernet is not getting its static ip on hotplug

Tags: debian, networking

I need to configure an ethernet interface to get its ip address dynamically if there is a dhcp server out there, and always have a static ip whether there is a dhcp server is present or not.

I have the following `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
...
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth0:1
allow-hotplug eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
  address 10.0.10.2
  netmask 255.255.255.0

...
```

If the cable is plugged while system is booting, the virtual interface (`eth0:1`) is getting its static ip. If the cable is plugged after system is up, `eth0` is getting its dynamic ip from dhcp server but `eth0:1` is not having any ip.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Ten years later, I encountered the same problem. The solution that worked for me was to add the following lines to the eth0 configuration:

```
        post-up ifup eth0:1 || true
        pre-down ifdown eth0:1 || true
```

I also replaced allow-hotplug with auto (source:https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/663955/601344).

So the complete configuration looks like:

```
auto lo eth0 eth0:1
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet dhcp
        post-up ifup eth0:1 || true
        pre-down ifdown eth0:1 || true


iface eth0:1 inet static
  address ...
  netmask ...
```

Perhaps this will help someone with an older system. ;)

Comment: Wow, looks much simpler. I will accept your answer as soon as I test it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround for now.

I keep this script alive by [supervisor](http://supervisord.org):

```
#!/bin/bash 

is_cable_plugged() {
 if [ "`ifconfig eth0|sed -n '/running/I p'`" == '' ];then echo no;else echo yes;fi
}


while true; do
    if [[ "$(is_cable_plugged)" == "no" ]]; then 
        while true; do
            if [[ "$(is_cable_plugged)" == "yes" ]]; then
                echo "DEBUG: Cable is now connected, reloading networking..." 
                /etc/init.d/networking reload
                break
            fi
            echo "DEBUG: Waiting for cable to be connected..."
            sleep 2s
        done
    fi
    echo "DEBUG: Cable is connected, do nothing..."
    sleep 10s
done
```